# I want to ignore a folder db_scripts from Istanbul coverage report

Tags: code-coverage, istanbul

I want to ignore a folder db_scripts from Istanbul coverage report structures of coverage is like app/db_scripts which I see in the report.

I am passing it as:-

"istanbul cover index.js  --dir ./documentation/contract-tests -x index.js -x '**/db_scripts/**'"

but still getting folder files in coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
-x '**/db_scripts/**'
```